# Swiching between open windows in Netbeans

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, netbeans

Is there any way to switch between open windows like for example in gnome terminal (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>,...)? <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is not comfortable for me.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `tabs`. You can simply do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page-up</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page-down</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> will let you choose.

To focus perspectives,

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> is for Editor,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is for Java Perspective,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is for File Perspective,
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> is for Output, etc..

Moreover, you can change these to whatever you like. Go to `Tools -> Options -> Keymap`, and there you go. And there are ready to use keymaps available for Eclipse, IntelliJ, and Emacs users.

Comment: http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2008/04/top-10-netbeans-ide-keyboard-shortcuts.html please refer this link for additional useful keyboard shortcuts for NetBeans IDE

Answer (score 0):

### Heading ##Toggling between Views:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd>) - Switch between open documents by order used
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDown</kbd> - Switch between open documents by order of tabs
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>PgDown</kbd> - Toggle between editor types
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> - Reopen recently closed file